# Active Gantt CompleteObjectMove

Tags: gantt-chart

I am evaluating this tool 
I need to fit every task one against each other when the user add o move a task
I have read something about completeobjectmove but I am not able to find anything

Thanks in advance

I will try to explain. I am interested in showing a graphical production planning. You can change orders (tasks) between machines (rows). When a task is inserted, moved o deleted I need to reorganize automatically the rest of other tasks one agaist each other.I am using VBN. Is there any way to automatically reorganize all the tasks in the same row?. If I insert a task i need to move the rest os the tasks to the right. If I delete a task o move to another row I need to move the rest of the tasks to the left.

I am Using VBN –

Comment: Just to clarify, are you referring to [ActiveGantt](http://www.sourcecodestore.com/Products/Activegantt_Gantt_Chart_Scheduler_Component.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes he is referring to ActiveGantt (but what version VBN, CSN, VBW, CSW, VBE, CSE or VC?). What language are you using Visual Basic 6, Visual Basic .NET, C#, C++, Visual Basic for Applications? The question does not contain enough information. Please explain in detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: I will try to explain. I am interested in showing a graphical production planning. You can change orders (tasks) between machines (rows). When a task is inserted, moved o deleted I need to reorganize automatically the rest of other tasks one agaist each other.I am using VBN. Is there any way to automatically reorganize all the tasks in the same row?. If I insert a task i need to move the rest os the tasks to the right. If I delete a task o move to another row I need to move the rest of the tasks to the left. Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no automatic way of doing this. The CompleteObjectChange Event would be triggered when you move a task or resize it. You would have to handle this event. When inserting you would have to handle the ObjectAdded Event. So you would insert a task and in the ObjectAdded event you would have to move your tasks to the right. And when you move or resize a task in the ObjectChanged event you would have to shift your tasks to the left.